# Structuremap - dependency injection - EF Core DBContext lifetime per request

Tags: asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core, structuremap

Has anyone had any luck setting up an EF Core DBContext with Structuremap "correctly" (what *is* correctly?)

DBContext needs to be a singleton across the lifetime of the request.

I understand that the default lifecycle is *Transient*. I understand that that will get a *nested container*, which effectively means "per request" when running under web api / mvc? ([see this](http://structuremap.github.io/the-container/nested-containers/))

But, looking at this code, isn't the `dbcontext` going to be an Application Lifetime singleton?

```
public class DistributedTaskRegistry : Registry
{
    public DistributedTaskRegistry()
    {
        For<DistributedTaskDbContext>().Use(() => new DistributedTaskDbContextFactory().CreateDbContext(null));
        For<IDistributedTaskRepository>().Use<DistributedTaskRepository>();
    }
}
```

**NB** this is a "legacy" .Net Framework 4.7 Web Api using EF Core

**Edit** What happened to `HttpContextScoped`?

Answer (score 0):

Confirmed: the default lifetime is *transient*, and with `StructureMap` that means *Per Request Lifetime*.

If you want an app lifetime *Singleton* you need to specify it.

```
For<IDistributedTaskRepository>().Use<DistributedTaskRepository>().Singleton();
```